# Upload de arquivos não carregando a extensão

Tags: php, arquivo, classes, upload

Olá, estou tentando gerar o nome do arquivo upado em `md5();`, mas a extensão do meu arquivo não funciona na hora do `upload`, segue a minha classe:

```
<?php

class Upload {

    private $_SupportedFormats = ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png'];

    private function encryption($str) {
        return md5($str);
    }

    private function verify_file($file) {
        if (is_array($file)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function verify_format($file) {
        if ($this->verify_file($file)) {
            if (in_array($file['type'], $this->_SupportedFormats)) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function upload_file($file) {
        if ($this->verify_format($file)) {
            move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], FOLDER_UPLOADS . '/' . $this->encryption($file['name']));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Este é o nome do arquivo que está sendo upado: `d26f85295e5c2da4634ee2bff0c83e1e`.

Gostaria que ficasse assim, (com a extensão)`d26f85295e5c2da4634ee2bff0c83e1e.png`.

O que há de errado na minha classe? Não entendo, se estou setando `$this->encryption($file['name']);` Por que está sumindo a extensão? Tô bolado com isso já.

Comment: O name se refere tanto ao nome do arquivo, quanto a extensão dele. Logo, você está transformando tudo em MD5. Você tem que passar pra MD5, depois adicionar a extensão manualmente. Pra saber a extensão você pode dar um explode no name original e pegar o que está depois do último ponto, ou simplesmente dar explode, passar o name pra MD5 e depois dar implode no name que virou MD5 + a extensão que foi separada no explode... enfim. Acho que já deu pra entender onde está o erro.

Comment: @ClaydersonFerreira, obrigado pelo comentário, marcaram minha pergunta como duplicata, eu já revirei a internet e não consigo encontrar uma solução. O seu comentário eu entendi, tentei dar um explode porém mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: @GuilhermeSpinXO a solução é exatamente o que eu respondi na que foi indicada no fechamento, é só acrescentar a extensão depois do MD5. Tem a linha de código praticamente pronta lá. Só usar MD5 no lugar do uniqid. Aliás, não vejo vantagem nenhuma em você usar MD5.

Comment: @Bacco, consegui, `move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], FOLDER_UPLOADS . '/' . $this->encryption('img_').pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION` meu problema agora é adicionar o ponto, eu usei o seu exemplo a exatamente 20 minutos atras e não consigo achar um lugar pra concatenar o `.` mas obrigado assim que eu conseguir eu atualizo a pergunta. meu arquivo agora ficou com este nome `de73ef9cd7306f6fff741643eb3423e8png`

Comment: o IMG_ você pode tirar também. Teste isso: `move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], FOLDER_UPLOADS . '/' . $this->encryption($file['name']) . '.' . pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` - Note que eu acrescentei o ponto igual você fez com a barra: `. '.' .`

Comment: Obrigado @Bacco deu certo... vc é o cara (y ...

Comment: @GuilhermeSpinXO tendo dúvida vá perguntando que a gente ajuda o quanto puder. O importante é você entender que se fecharam como duplicata, é por ter a solução na outra, pois ninguém em sã consciência fecha pra atrapalhar o usuário. Enganos às vezes acontecem, é claro, mas no caso, fazia sentido. Depois dê uma pensada se precisa mesmo usar MD5. O `uniqid()` nunca repete (e não precisa usar o nome original pra gerar o hash, se for guardar o hash no DB).

Comment: Então cara estou usando md5 apenas pra deixar os nomes quase padrões vamos assim dizer... pra não ficar aquela coisa feia. Ah e me equivoquei mesmo ao dizer que marcaram como duplicata, e acabou me ajudando... :)